# search and replace string in all files

Tags: editors

I realize that this might not strictly be a LaTeX question but I have still decided to post the question here as other's might have the same problem on occasion.

I am working on a rather large document at the moment that contains a bunch of equations. Instead of writing them as:

```
    Q^{h}_{Con} = 0.15 \cdot Q^{h}_{Transm} + ...
```

I would rather do this:

```
\newcommand{\qCon}{Q^{h}_{Con}}
\newcommand{\qTransm}{Q^{h}_{Transm}}
...
\qCon = 0.15 \cdot \qTransm + ...
```

Now it is not hard to do this if you have that idea when you start writing on a document. In my case however I already have many pages written (including a nomenclature). Now I would like to replace all mentions of e.g. `$Q^{h}_{Con}$` with `$\qCon$`. Doing this I could make sure that I don't have a typo somewhere and up with a `$Q^{h}_{Com}$`.

Going through all files on their own is way too complicated and the tex editor I am using only offers search and replace in all opened files. So I have tried to use the Terminal (on Mac) to do so. I have been able to use 'grep' to find all the instances of e.g. `$Q^{h}_{Con}$` but could not figure out how to replace it with `$\qCon$`.

Anyone has an idea?

Comment: What about [sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed)?

Comment: @IanThompson Indeed: `sed 's/Q^{h}_{\([^}]*\)}/q\1/g'` should do the trick. (Made minor correction.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

something like

```
for i in *.tex
do
sed -i -e 's/Q^{h}_{\([a-zA-Z]*\)}/\\q\1 /g' $i
done
```

Probably does something. (Save a copy of your files first:-)

Comment: `sed -i.bak ...` is good for back ups :)

Comment: @cmhughes yes although I never trust it, I'd zip up the directory first:-)

Comment: That doesn't work as it only affects `Q^{h}_{Con}`s.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen hm seems like I only read the last line of the question in detail:-)

Comment: `[^}]*` is more general.

Comment: @MarcvanDongen it's more general which is why I didn't use it as if there were (say) digits there you don't want `\q123` as it wouldn't work. The end result has to be a csname starting with q.

Comment: I had ovelooked this is part of a command sequence.

Comment: @MatoBehr I had omitted `do` where you have a `?` in your comment (this is bash syntax)  then for sed `-i` says to edit each file in-place (destroying the original!!!) using the expression in teh `-e` clause which does the replacement you asked for.

Comment: there are a few things I don't quite get.
What is '\([a-zA-Z]*\)', '\\q\1' and '$i' doing?

Comment: For this solution to work, is it needed that all *.tex files are in one directory? So far I have them sorted into folders.

Comment: `[a-zA-Z]` is a single character in the ranges a-z or A-Z  `[a-zA-Z]*` is 0 or more of those (that is, it's a word) It is surrounded by a regexp group `\( ... \)` so that whatever word matches that part can be re-used in the replacement text where \\1 appears (standing for the first group) This is standard regular expression syntax, as used in most editors.

Comment: @MatoBehr as written yes but you can replace `*.tex` by `*/*.tex` if they are all one level down or by `\`find . -name \*.tex\`` to find all .tex files at any depth below current directory but this is way off topic for this tex site:-)

Comment: @MatoBehr `$i` is the loop variable ie it is (at each iteration) the filename to be passed to sed.